# How can I set createdAt and updatedAt as timestamp not timestamp(6) when generating a migration?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have in my project the MySQL database and TypeORM.

My entity is defined as below:

```
export const CompanyRadarTypeEntity = new EntitySchema<ICompanyRadarTypeEntity>({
    name: 'companyRadarType',
    tableName: 'companyRadarType',
    columns: {
        idCompanyRadarType: {
            type: Number,
            primary: true,
            generated: true,
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
        },
        idCompany: {
            type: Number,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: 'timestamp',
            default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            nullable: false,
            createDate: true,
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: 'timestamp',
            default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            nullable: false,
            updateDate: true,
        },
    },
    relations: {
        company: {
            type: 'many-to-one',
            target: 'company',
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'idCompany',
                referencedColumnName: 'idCompany',
            },
        },
        companyRadars: {
            type: 'one-to-many',
            target: 'companyRadar',
            inverseSide: 'companyRadarType',
        },
    },
});
```

When I generate the migration with typeorm it gives me the following SQL:

```
await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE \`companyRadarType\` (
                \`idCompanyRadarType\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                \`type\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                \`idCompany\` int NOT NULL,
                \`createdAt\` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                \`updatedAt\` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
                PRIMARY KEY (\`idCompanyRadarType\`)
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB
        `);
```

But when I run the migration it gives me the error: **Error during migration run: QueryFailedError: ER_INVALID_DEFAULT: Invalid default value for 'createdAt'**

I noticed that when I remove the createDate: true and updateDate: true from my entity it replaces the timestamp(6) type to timestamp, but the SQL does not have the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP part.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a [date function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-current_timestamp/), so must be called thusly:

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`

This will give you a value like this: `2023-12-20 16:21:28.62815`